# Is it possible to click on labels in Mapbox like on Google maps?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Is it possible to click on labels in Mapbox and highlight the city like on Google maps?

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9btR3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

All visible map elements, including labels, in a mapbox-gl map can be clicked.

see https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/

In that example, instead of catching the mousemove event, catch the click event like this:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);
    document.getElementById('features').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(features, null, 2);
});
```